# Facebook login button width and height

Tags: html, css, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

is there anyway to manipulate facebook login plugin? i choose large but height and width is not enough for me. i need to manipulate that button's height and espacially width i tried this:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-width="430" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-button-type="continue_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="true" scope="public_profile,email" auth_type="rerequest" onlogin="checkLoginState();"></div>
```

Comment: i cant manipulate that

Comment: No, it is not possible to manipulate the look of that button beyond the options described in the documentation. (Other than scaling it up with a CS transformation, but that usually looks terrible.) But you can use your own custom button and use it to call `FB.login`, and handle login that way.

Comment: yeah i started to make my own button thanks for your comments